# How to increase debezium / kafka connect performance for initial snapshot of millions of records and enable snapshot parallely if possible?

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

**Usecase:**
I have 700+ tables in sql server database and have high volume of data in each table. Each table is having 20-50 millions of records and I need to run debezium on all tables for initaial snapshot and push them to kafka.

**Tools used:**

1. Kafka 3.3.1
2. Debezium 2.0
3. Apicurio regitry
4. Avro convertor

**Analysis:** Taking snapshot of 1 table with 50 million records almost takes 6 hours to get complete. FYI, I have set following properties set and have tried various values for them

```
offset.flush.timeout.ms=60000
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
max.request.size=20485760
max.batch.size=30000
max.queue.size=200000
```

But performance is not increasing.

**Problem:** Considering many tables and since snapshot works sequentially, It will take days to take initial snapshot, how can I resolve this problem?

TIA

Comment: Have you tried running multiple connectors each with a subset of whitelisted tables? With that, also try not putting larger tables in the same config

Comment: Yes, running multiple debezium instance says dbhistory.<servername> topic can't be shared.

Comment: Do you need the history topic?

Comment: Not sure, I didnt create it. Debezium creates it and manages it may be for some internal processes. I dont use it in any way, not sure if that is reqd

Comment: I don't think it is required. But also, the name of that history topic should be able to be overridden per unique connector config, as suggested

Comment: From my experience, multiple connectors for a subset of tables might help.
There is also the fact how fast the DB is returning results for the 30000 batch size and which indexes are being used by the SQL queries. 
Also, since snapshots ideally should be a 1 time thing, it's ok to run a bit longer...

Comment: @TudorPlugaru Thanks for the valuable input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Debezium 2.2.0, it is possible to snapshot multiple tables in parallel, as explained in their blog [post](https://debezium.io/blog/2023/04/20/debezium-2-2-final-released/#new-parallel-snapshots).

To define how many tables should be snapshotted in parallel, you should set the following parameter in the Debezium connector config:

```
snapshot.max.threads=4
```

If this value is greater than 1, then snapshot parallelism will be enabled.